# como acrescentar aspas com virgula em uma variável que vem em array?

Tags: php

estou tentando fazer uma variável vinda do banco que vem em as informações juntas tipo `1234` eu precisaria deixar essas informações assim `'1','2','3','4'` para colocar em um select estou usando o `echo substr("','".$nota_fiscal."',",1);`

porém me mostra assim '1','2','3','4'` alguém pode me ajudar.

para um caractere a sugestão do pedro funcionou porem tenho casos de que vem com mais tipo 490569770099 e preciso deixar assim '49056977','770099' o quantidade de caracteres vem variadas.

Comment: esse é um exemplo do dado vindo do banco de dados? tem um mais detalhado?

Comment: E se o valor for maior que 9? Chegou `1234`, como você sabe que é `1,2,3,4` e não `1,2,34` ou `12,34` ou `123,4`?

Comment: cada linha é um numero a primeira linha traz 1 a segunda 2 e por ai vai...

Comment: Linhas? Que linhas? Quais são as regras para reconhecer os valores? Usando o exemplo que você mesmo deu, `490569770099`, como saberemos que precisa separar em `49056977,770099` e não em `490569,77770099`?

Comment: essas informações esta vindo do banco

Answer (score 4):

Supondo que os valores serão apenas entre 0 e 9.

Primeiro separar cada caracter da string original, utilizando [`str_split`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-split.php).
Depois juntar todas as partes com uma "cola" que você desejar, utilizando [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php)

```
<?php

    $texto = '1234';
    $aux = str_split($texto);
    $texto = implode("','",$aux);
    $texto = "'".$texto."'";
    var_dump($texto);

?>
```

Comment: Pedro isso mesmo deu certo obrigado

Comment: @teste, vale a pena marcar a resposta como aceita ;)